# Customizing an SVG in Mediawiki

Tags: html, svg, mediawiki

I have ImageMagick 6.8.5-6 up and running on MediaWiki 1.20.2 (Running on Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5).  It's doing it's thing and appears to be functioning perfectly.  I'm trying to figure out how I can pass parameters to the SVG, either in wikicode or using the html tag to wrap the svg in an object tag.

Here is the SVG I'm using.  (created on http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/)  This is just a simple arrow or tag I'm going to use to point at stuff and label stuff.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 100" width="100%" height="100%">
  <path stroke="#000000" id="Arrow" d="m2.749992,2.750002l106.118515,0l88.431496,47.250097l-88.431496,47.249901l-106.118515,0l0,-94.499998z" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
```

I need to figure out how to pass the width, height, and fill parameters, so I can set the size and color of the tag.

Wikicode doesn't work from what I've tried, so I've enabled raw html and I'm calling it like this.

```
<html>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/wiki/images/3/32/Arrow.svg">
  </object>
</html>
```

How I get those parameters from a wiki page into that svg I have no idea?

Edit: 
 
Desktops in my environment are running IE8, which doesn't support SVG.  I just have to figure out how to tell ImageMagick to 'fill' the svg with a given color before it generates the png thumbnail.

Comment: Have you tried to add the SVG as an inline HTML?

Comment: Yea, I should have mentioned that I'm trying to get this to work in IE8.  Enterprise desktop deterines what version of IE is on the desktops sadly.  ImageMagick is doing its thing, I just have to figure out how to tell ImageMagick how to change the Fill property before it generates the png thumbnail at a given size.

Comment: Idea: Raphael.js works with IE6-8 (using VML), if you dynamically generate <path> with Raphael (browser-size), then you skip the imagemagick part and focus on 'fill' issues.

Comment: What do you mean "wikicode doesn't work"? [Image markup](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images) definitely allows to alter width (and height), make sure you configured your thumbnailer correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass parameters into SVG, but you can manipulate it with Javascript. If you just want to position it, you can just position the svg element in the right place just as if it was an image.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script>

   function pointAtMe(e) {
     var svg = document.getElementById("arrow");
     svg.style.display = "block";
     svg.style.position = "absolute";
     svg.style.top = (e.target.offsetTop - 40) + "px";
     svg.style.left = (e.target.offsetLeft - 110) + "px";
   }

   </script>
   <style>
     OBJECT { position: absolute; display: none } /* hide initially */
     BUTTON { display: block; margin: 100 auto }
   </style>
 </head>

 <body>

 <object id="arrow" width="100px" height="100px">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 200 100" width="100%" height="100%">
    <path stroke="#000000" id="Arrow" d="m2.749992,2.750002l106.118515,0l88.431496,47.250097l-88.431496,47.249901l-106.118515,0l0,-94.499998z" stroke-width="3"/>
   </svg>
 </object>

<div>
  <button onclick="pointAtMe(event)">Button 1</button>
  <button onclick="pointAtMe(event)">Button 2</button>
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Note that we have to wrap it in an object element because svg elements cannot be styled.

If you want to be more clever, such as altering the contents of the SVG dynamically, you can also do that with JS.

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner.  After playing around with this method it suited my needs.  Thanks!